# Crocodoc - embedding document with real-time changes

Tags: real-time, crocodoc

I'm using Crocodoc.com service to embed documents in a web page. Everything works fine, except the real-time collaboration feature (if someone makes a change to the document, the change should be reflected in real time for all viewers).

None of the examples from their website seem to work this way and it's not mentioned anywhere in the documentation, but I have found an example on another site which works:

http://demo.wikispaces.umb.edu/Crocodoc+Real-time+Annotation.

This document is embedded using the previos version of Crocodoc API (v1).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a [real-time web system like websockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/), i.e., ["push" technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology) in order for each user to see the freshly added content.

There there is a "socket" that is kept open and all "subscribers" can get the "message" and you will put some JS on the page that contains the crocodoc such that the changes get implemented.